# Updating a document library word template

Tags: 2013, document-library, document-template, quick-parts

We recently migrated to SP 2013. We have a document library that uses a word template containing column data from SP. Somehow during the migration, the properties in the word documents were broken so when you open existing templates, they only display the column names, not the data. There is one exception: one of the fields is still populated. When I create a new document, the same thing happens. I then opened the word template, deleted and re-added a couple columns, saved it, and created a new list item. The fields I re-added were populated correctly.

Is there a way to update all the existing documents (refresh the fields) without having to open and edit each document individually? I think during the migration, all but one of the fields lost their association with the list columns.